# Minesweeper recursion for cascading reveal

Tags: java, minesweeper

So I have the majority of a method that will cascade reveal in a minesweeper game. I have a board of the solution, and one of the current grid. But the problem is that when I run into the 0 spaces, I get a stack overflow error at the recursive call.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
public static void revealCell(int row, int col, char[][] grid, char[][] answers) {
    System.out.println(row + " " + col);
    if(row < 0|| row > 4){
        System.out.println("bad");
        return;
    }
    if(col < 0|| col > 4){
        System.out.println("bad");
        return;
    }
    if(answers[row][col] == 'B'){
        grid[row][col] = answers[row][col];
        return;
    }
    if(answers[row][col] == '1'||answers[row][col] == '2'||answers[row][col] == '3'||answers[row][col] == '4'||answers[row][col] == '5'){
        grid[row][col] = answers[row][col];
        return;
    }

    if(answers[row][col] == '0'){
        System.out.println("go");
        grid[row][col] = answers[row][col];
        for(int i = row-1; i <= row +1; i++){
            for(int j = col-1; j<= col +1;j++){
                revealCell(i,j, grid, answers);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your fors around the `revealCell()` forces it to be called for the same 0 cell over and over and over. You can keep track of the cells you've visited already and check that before calling `revealCell()`.

Comment: I think I figured it out, I just added

if(grid[i][j] != '0')

around the recursive call

Comment: Another matrix, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Your nested loop is repeatedly calling `revealCell(row, col, ...)`.  Either restructure your loops, or else simply insert a `if i!=row && j!=col` guard.

You may still have infinite recursion after this change.  It has been awhile since I coded a minesweeper game, but IIRC I used four different recursive calls in order to avoid repeatedly checking the same cells: one call searched the upper-left quadrant of the board from the point of the mine collision (increasing-row, decreasing-column), one searched the upper-right quadrant (increasing-row, increasing-column), etc.